# Group by using agg and count

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have the following group by in pandas

```
   df = df.groupby("pred_text1").agg({
        "rouge_score":"first","pred_text1":"first", 
        "input_text":"first", "target_text":"first", "prefix":"first"})
```

I want to have another columns which counts the number in each group (repetition of each `pred_text`)

I know that using `transform('count')` after `groupby` can add such a new column, but I still need `agg` function too.

Comment: easier with a [mcve]

Comment: @doesitmatter it's just a groupby

Comment: You can pass a list of things to aggregate. For example `agg({'pred_text1': ['first', 'count']})` will produce 2 columns `('pred_text1', 'first')` and `('pred_text1', 'count')`

Comment: @MYousefi then how to renamed them to reguilar names

Comment: What names should they have? You generally just rename them after.

Comment: @MYousefi `pred_text1` and `preds_count`

Answer (score 1):

You can use `pd.NamedAgg` function. (Pandas 0.25+)

### Code:

```py
import pandas as pd

# A sample dataframe
df = pd.DataFrame({
        'pred_text1': [chr(ord('A')+i%3) for i in range(10)],
        'rouge_score': [chr(ord('A')+i%5) for i in range(10)],
        'input_text': [chr(ord('A')+i%7) for i in range(10)],
        'target_text': [chr(ord('A')+i%9) for i in range(10)],
        'prefix': [chr(ord('A')+i%11) for i in range(10)],
    })

# Aggregation
df = df.groupby("pred_text1").agg(
        rouge_score=pd.NamedAgg("rouge_score", "first"),
        pred_text1=pd.NamedAgg("pred_text1", "first"),
        input_text=pd.NamedAgg("input_text", "first"),
        target_text=pd.NamedAgg("target_text", "first"),
        prefix=pd.NamedAgg("prefix", "first"),
        pred_count=pd.NamedAgg("pred_text1", "count"),
    )
```

### Input:

| (index) | pred_text1 | rouge_score | input_text | target_text | prefix |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 0 | A | A | A | A | A |
| 1 | B | B | B | B | B |
| 2 | C | C | C | C | C |
| 3 | A | D | D | D | D |
| 4 | B | E | E | E | E |
| 5 | C | A | F | F | F |
| 6 | A | B | G | G | G |
| 7 | B | C | A | H | H |
| 8 | C | D | B | I | I |
| 9 | A | E | C | A | J |

### Output:

| (index) | rouge_score | pred_text1 | input_text | target_text | prefix | pred_count |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| A | A | A | A | A | A | 4 |
| B | B | B | B | B | B | 3 |
| C | C | C | C | C | C | 3 |

Answer (score 1):

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame({'Group': ['G1', 'G1', 'G2', 'G3', 'G2', 'G1'], 'ValueLabel': [0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 2]})
```

You can do this in a few steps:
First aggregate.

```
df = df.groupby('Group').agg({'ValueLabel': ['first', 'count']})
```

The new columns are a `pd.MultiIndex` type which we will flatten. After that we can create a mapping of the names to the labels we want and rename the columns.

```
df.columns = df.columns.to_flat_index()
mapper = {label: new_label for label, new_label in zip \
         (pd.MultiIndex.from_product([['ValueLabel'], \
         ['first', 'count']]), ['ValueFirstLabel', 'ValueCountLabel'])}
df.rename(mapper, axis=1, inplace=True)
```